# Why does overflow: hidden move <body> to top of the page?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've created a scrolling modal window that requires `overflow: hidden` to be applied to the body, when the modal is open, to prevent the body from scrolling. However, `overflow: hidden` causes my body to jump up to the top of the page. Why is this is how do I prevent this from happening?

**edit:** Here is the css for my `<body>`:

```
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  font-smooth: always;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Here is the css for my modal window:

```
.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.menu .options {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  padding: 120px 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu .menu_bg {
  background-color: #b4f0b4;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

and here is the HTML for my modal window:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="options"></div>
    <div class="menu_bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably blocking margin collapse. Do you have any top-level elements in body with margins?

Comment: @BoltClock I don't understand what you mean by "top-level elements." Are you referring to the `<body>`'s immediate children?

Comment: Yes, I am. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BoltClock There were two elements with margins. I changed margin to padding but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 4):

Your body is probably in `height: 100%`, just add `height: auto` at the same time you add `overflow: hidden` and it should be ok.

Answer (score -1):

It's because `<body>` has a default of **8px margin** so when you hide the `<body>` the margin goes away.

Set your body to `body{margin: 0px}` and it will no longer jump.

**See example:** hover body to see the jump

http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/Lmh3nt6p/

Comment: Added `margin: 0 !important;` and am still having the same problem. The issue is that if I scroll to the bottom of the page, then add `overflow: hidden` to `<body>` via jquery, it jumps back to the top of the page.

Comment: It's probably best that you post your code at this point, otherwise it will continue to be a guessing game.